# I'm Using jQuery for Toggle in wordPress to change menu icon but its still does not change?

Tags: jquery, css, wordpress, megamenu, wp-mega-menu

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  jQuery("#toggleMegaMenu").click(function() {
    jQuery(".wpac-mega-menu").slideToggle();
    JQuery("#toggleMegaMenu ").toggleClass('fa-solid fa-caret-up');
  });
});
 </script>
```

**I have applied jQuery to make megamenu toggle, Toggle is work like when I click mega-menu appears but Icon is not change to toggleclass icon when I click on menu button for mega-menu**

Here is Video Link Attached.
[1](https://www.loom.com/share/396caea340944715b917839b6f83a993)

Comment: `JQuery` -> `jQuery`. Voting to close as a typo

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you're putting `JQuery` instead of `jQuery` when you call the `toggleClass` method.